# Passing data to another component in vue.js inside Laravel

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

I have below HTML code in one of my Laravel blade (view) file.

```
<div id="search-applicants" class="container2">
    <div class="leftbar">
        <leftbar></leftbar>
    </div>
    <div class="applicant-list">
        <applicants></applicants>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I send value from `leftbar` component to `applicants` component ?

Comment: Try to look here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch

Comment: And also here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [global event bus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/) for bidirectional communication.

```
// event-bus.js
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();

// leftbar.vue
import { EventBus } from './event-bus.js';

export default {
  methods: {
    onClick(value) {
     EventBus.$emit('click::event', value);
   }
 }
}

// applicants.vue
import { EventBus } from './event-bus.js';

EventBus.$on('click::event', payload => {
   console.log(payload)
});
```